# Custom Delete record code

Tags: wordpress

I want to delete record custom using wpdb but its not working ...help me

```
<?php
              global $wpdb;
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'salary';
                $mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE id = $id", ARRAY_N );if ( isset( $_GET['delete'] ) ) {    
$wpdb->delete( $tablename, array( 'id' => $id ), array( '%d' ) );echo 'Record successfully deleted';}else{
echo 'There are some problem ,you  can not  delete';}?>
```

Comment: where is the `$table` defined? also remove single quotes around `$table` 
`$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ), array( '%d' ) );`

Comment: Still its not working...I have edited

Comment: `var_dump($wpdb->last_error);` check for error , i m sure you `$table` is undefined or its empty or the table doesn't exists.

Comment: yes , i edited $table to $tablename and its defined. But still not working..

Comment: did you check for error ? `var_dump($wpdb->last_error);`

Comment: yes and its shows ... string '' (length=0) , and still not working

Comment: i guess `$id` is empty in that case

Comment: No ,i also delete another row but still shows string ' '(length=0) ...help